# Error handling in SASS

Tags: sass

I'd like to handle some errors in my scss code.

Imagine this code.

```
$color: 12;

a {
  @if (type-of($color) != color) {
    // trow an error
  }
}
```

Now I use a mixin, that takes some params and calls `@error` or `@warn`.

```
@mixin log($type, $message) {
  @if ($type == error) {
    @error $message;
  } @else {
    //
  }
}
```

But I don't want to call it every time via `@include`: `@include log(error, "message");`.

I'd wont something like this:

```
a {
  @if (type-of($color) != color) {
    log(error, "message");
  }
}
```

So, is there a way to write a function (or not a function) to call it inside a selector?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally `mixins` should be used to create **property** and **value** pairs. `Functions` are expected to **return** values so can be used any where you Sass / CSS expects a value

```
@function log($type, $message) {
  @if ($type == error) {
    @return $message;
  } @else {
    //return something else
  }
}

a {
  @if (type-of($color) != color) {
    @error log(error, 'message'); 
    // $type == error so log(error, 'message') returns 'message'
    // so entire line is interpreted as @error 'message'  
  }
}
```

In this example the only difference was using `@error` for the `function` instead of `@include` for the `mixin`.

However imagine if you needed to change a colour based on a certain value like a width and log some errors at the same time.

```
@function get-colour($width) {
  $color: green;
  @if ($width < 10) {
    @warn 'This size is too small';
    $color: red;
  }
  @return $color;
}

div {
  background-color: get-colour(12); //returns green colour for div
}

p {
  background-color: get-colour(5); //logs warning and returns red colour for p
}
```

While a `mixin` would return `property: value`, a `function` returns **ONLY** a value which can be used on different properties.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit. There is no way to handle errors without `@mixins`. `@include log(error, "message");` is the only solution.

Comment: Actually `functions` can be used to handle `errors`. In this situation the difference would be negligible but it can be handy in some situations. You can check this [tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-sass--cms-19996)

Comment: @BlackEnigma I didn't find how to call function inside selector or mixin to throw error or warning.